# How do i change a global variable inside javascript function? (solutions from this site not working!)

Tags: javascript, php, forms, variables, global

my code should allow me to alternate between two values 
for my 'hiddenvalue' input, but despite the alert confirming that formquestion has changed to '2', when formvalue is executed again it still alerts '2' - it is not switching back and forth from the if statement to the else statement. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

```
var formquestion = 1;

function formvalue(){

    if (formquestion === 1){
        document.getElementById("hiddenvalue").value = "form1"; 
        formquestion = 2;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("hiddenvalue").value = "form2"; 
        formquestion = 1;
    }

    alert("Value of 'formquestion' outside the function " + formquestion);      
}
```

Comment: how are you calling the function?

Comment: Your mistake is probably somewhere else. Your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/sfc8vw53/

Comment: User submits a poll response and the following code calls the formvalue function;   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="formvalue()"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="form1" />
  <input type="hidden" id="hiddenvalue" name="MM_insert" value="" />

Comment: I think the problem is i'm submitting a form and it refreshes the page. Looking into that now. Thanks for your help.